# Bucle for iteración variable python

Tags: python, bucles

Ante todo dar las gracias de antemano y pedir disculpas por esta duda completamente intrascendente, hace 2 semanas que empecé a programar y soy un completo desastre. Mi duda es muy sencilla, o eso creo.

```
 elif interes >= float(0) or interes <= float(1):
            sl = int(input("Seleccione el año actual: "))
            sl1 = int(input("¿A qué año quiere llevar la actualización?: "))
            for x in range(sl,sl1-1,-1):
                x1 = 0
                **if x <= sl:
                    x1 = x1+1
                    op1 = cuenta / ((1 + interes) ** x1)
                    print("La actualización en el año", x, "es de ", op1, "euros")
            break**
```

Como se puede observar en el *for* de *python*, intento crear una variable que se llama "x1" teniendo esta un valor inicial de 0. El problema radica en que no consigo aumentar el valor de la misma en +1 cada vez que se produzca una iteración, de manera que ese valor quede guardado para la operación inmediatamente posterior y se sume tantas veces como dure la iteración.

Espero que se entienda mi duda y me haya expresado bien.

Muchas gracias comunidad.

Comment: Si defines la variable dentro del `for`, obviamente la va a redefinir en cada vuelta del `for`, volviendo a ponerla a `0`. Defínela fuera, antes de entrar en el `for`.

Answer (score 0):

La comparación

```
if x <= sl:
```

es innecesaria dado que los valores que pueda tomar `x`nunca serán menores a `sl`.

Tienes tambióen que inicializa la variable `x1` antes de entrar al `for`

Demo:

```
cuenta = 1000
interes = 0.01 # 1%
sl = 2021
sl1 = 2015
x1 = 0
for x in range(sl, sl1 - 1, -1):
    x1 = x1 + 1
    op1 = cuenta / ((1 + interes) ** x1)
    print("La actualización en el año", x, "es de ", op1, "euros")
```

produce:

```
La actualización en el año 2021 es de  990.09900990099 euros
La actualización en el año 2020 es de  980.2960494069209 euros
La actualización en el año 2019 es de  970.5901479276444 euros
La actualización en el año 2018 es de  960.9803444828162 euros
La actualización en el año 2017 es de  951.4656876067487 euros
La actualización en el año 2016 es de  942.0452352542067 euros
La actualización en el año 2015 es de  932.7180547071354 euros
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo sin necesidad de incrementar "a mano" la variable `x1`, si haces uso de la función `enumerate()`. Esta función recibe un iterable (en tu caso sería el `range()`) y opcionalmente un valor de `start`. El resultado es otro iterable que  devuelve en cada iteración una pareja de valores, el primero es un contador que va incrementando automáticamente (comenzando en el valor `start`), y el segundo es el valor del iterable que corresponda a ese momento.

Por ejemplo:

```
for contador, valor in enumerate(range(2000, 1995, -1), start=1):
  print("Contador =", contador, "; valor =", valor)
```

imprimiría:

```
Contador = 1 ; valor = 2000
Contador = 2 ; valor = 1999
Contador = 3 ; valor = 1998
Contador = 4 ; valor = 1997
Contador = 5 ; valor = 1996
```

En tu caso por tanto lo usarías así:

```
cuenta = 1000
interes = 0.01 # 1%
sl = 2021
sl1 = 2015

for x1, x in enumerate(range(sl, sl1 - 1, -1), start=1):
    op1 = cuenta / ((1 + interes) ** x1)
    print("La actualización en el año", x, "es de ", op1, "euros")
```